# how to pass args pattern factory java

Tags: java, object, design-patterns, factory

i tring to implement a factory pattern in java, but i have some probleme

i have the class **AbstractAction** that is the abstract class for subclasses like MapMoveAction, CutAction

and the class **ActionFactory** that is the factory for creating instace of concrete class, the action factory class contain a static method **createAction** that take a string as parameter for identifying the concrect class to create

but my probleme is that each concrecte class take differente parameter when he need to be constructed :

```
 public class ActionFactory {

    public AbstractAction createAction(String uniqueName) {

        // TODO
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CutAction extends AbstractAction{

    public static final String UNIQUE_NAME = "cut";
    List<Resource> resources;

    public CutAction(List<Resource> resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
    } 

    @Override
    public String getActionCommand() {
        StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder(UNIQUE_NAME);
        command.append(" ");

        for(Resource resource : resources) {
            command.append(resource.getName());
            command.append(",");
        }

        command.deleteCharAt(command.lastIndexOf(","));

        return command.toString();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class UseAction extends AbstractAction{

    public static final String UNIQUE_NAME = "use";

    int cell;

    public UseAction(int cell) {
        this.cell = cell;
    }

    @Override
    public String getActionCommand() {
        return UNIQUE_NAME  + " " + cell;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) also says to have an abstract factory with concrete factory subclasses.

> The essence of this pattern is to "Define an interface for creating an object, but let the classes that implement the interface decide which class to instantiate. The Factory method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses."

Therefore, you need to make your `ActionFactory` abstract:

```
public abstract class ActionFactory {
    public abstract AbstractAction createAction();
}
```

Note, that the `createAction` method does not need a parameter anymore. Then you write concrete factories, such as

```
public class CutActionFactory extends ActionFactory {
    @Override
    public CutAction createAction() {
        // This factory knows how to create CutAction instances.
        return new CutAction(createResources())
    }
    private List<Resource> createResources { ... }
}
```